# Swiper slide - showing last slide 100%

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm tried to create a slider using swiper js. Is there a way to get similar as per Image?

[image: Swiper slider show last slide 100% from left side]

1. For the 1,2 slider show 100% and 3 slide with 60% and move two slide at a time.
2. For last slide show only 3rd slide.

```
const swiperUserGuide = new Swiper('.swiper-userguide', {
  loop: false,
  slidesPerView: 2.7,
  slidesPerGroup: 2,
  centeredSlides: false,
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  spaceBetween: 40,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  on: {
    reachEnd: function () {
      const numberOfSlides = this.slides.length - 1;
      if(numberOfSlides) {
        document.querySelector('.swiper-userguide .swiper-slide:last-child').classList.add('swiper-slide-last');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Try this: https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view-auto (Anyway it is hard to understand your Q).

Answer (score 2):

adding **slidePerView** and **SpaceBetween** will solve it

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 16,
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            slidesPerView: "1.2",
            shortSwipes: false
        },
        500: {
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            slidesPerView: "2",
            shortSwipes: false
        },
        1024: {
            preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            slidesPerView: "4.1",
            shortSwipes: false
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

For me works CSS `box-sizing: border-box` applied to the `.swiper-slide` selector

Answer (score 0):

cssMode: true,

Worked for me when the last slide was being cut off

Answer (score 0):

I added the right margin to the last child of the swiper-slide.

Ex: .swiper-slide:last-child { margin-right: 10rem !important; }

Or you can add an Empty Slide